# Setting a default value in choicfield in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a model field like this --

```
class Country(models.Model):
    country = CountryField()
```

From which i have created a form like this --

```
class CountryForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CountryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['country'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'class': 'form-control'})

    class Meta:
        model = xyz
        fields = ['country']
```

I have used django-country to create the country field.

How can i set a default value/a country selected at forms ?

Example: django-country have countries like this --- ('BD', 'Bangladesh'), ('An','Angola') etc. If i want to **Angola** be selected than i need to set a default value of **An**.

Comment: Have you tried passing the keyword argument 'default' in CountryField?

Comment: I want to do it without setting default at model.

Answer (score 1):

In order to take account initial value in Django choice field, I made something like this :

```
form.fields['country'].initial = "what do you expect"
```

For example, in my script, I have :

```
form.fields['sex'].initial = Person.sex
```

In my case, `Person` is a Django model where all person's informations are located.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an instance of your form, you should pass the keyword argument `initial` [to set an initial value for the field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values)

```
form = CountryForm(initial={'country': 'An'})
```